# Input_shape value of dense layer that get's input from concatenation layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensor, layer

I'm going through the Machine Learning Crash Course from Google, and I encountered something regarding input_shapes I can't understand. We are going to have 2 examples, both in which the input is concatenated into 1 tensor before it is fed to the first dense layer, yet the input_shape value will be different.

Here's how the dataset looks like. (note, we are using pandas.dataframe) (note, the first column before "longitude" is are the indexes of the rows after reindexing the dataset)

```
         longitude  latitude  housing_median_age  total_rooms  total_bedrooms  population  households  median_income  median_house_value
3066     -117.81     33.81                19.0       3154.0           390.0      1404.0       384.0         8.9257            431800.0
6099     -118.23     34.15                26.0       1649.0           522.0      1332.0       483.0         3.1004            257100.0
14625    -122.17     37.75                48.0       1751.0           390.0       935.0       349.0         1.4375             90000.0
7157     -118.32     33.75                37.0       1080.0           135.0       366.0       142.0        11.6677            500001.0
5665     -118.18     33.87                38.0       2664.0           626.0      1627.0       604.0         3.7527            161900.0
```

Original Input Layers are:

```
inputs = {
    'latitude':
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32,
                              name='latitude'),
    'longitude':
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32,
                              name='longitude')
}
```

Then we concatenate these in different ways, and here's where the confusion kicks in.

Example 1:

```
def create_model(my_inputs, my_learning_rate, METRICS):
  # Use a Concatenate layer to concatenate the input layers into a single tensor.
  # as input for the Dense layer. Ex: [input_1[0][0], input_2[0][0]]
    concatenated_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(my_inputs.values())
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,), name='dense_layer', activation=tf.sigmoid)
    dense_output = dense(concatenated_inputs)
    my_outputs = {
    'dense': dense_output,
    }
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=my_outputs)...
```

Example 2:

```
**# Concatenate latitude and longitude into a single tensor as input for the Dense layer.**
concatenate_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([latitude, longitude])

dense_output = layers.Dense(
    units=1, input_shape=(2,), name='dense_layer')(concatenate_layer)

# Define an output dictionary we'll send to the model constructor.
outputs = {
  'dense_output': dense_output
}
```

I have absolutely 0 clue why even though we concatenate 2 inputs into 1 tensor both times, do we use different input_shape values.

I googled a ton, yet couldn't find an answer through which I could understand the problem.